# How to send/receive multiple files via TIdTCPServer/TidTCPClient at once?

Tags: stream, delphi-7, indy-9

This is my coding of sending single file.

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServerExecute(AThread: TIdPeerThread);
begin
  ...
  try
    ...
    AFileStream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead + fmShareDenyNone);

    try
      AThread.Connection.WriteStream(AFileStream, true, true);
    finally
      AFileStream.Free;
    end;
  except
    AThread.Connection.WriteLn('N');
  end;
  AThread.Connection.Disconnect;
end;
```

If I had multiple files to send at once, please suggest me how to do it?

Is it possible to read it at once using

```
procedure TForm1.ReadImageFromServer(ACmd: string);
begin    
  with IdTCPClient1 do begin
    ...
    AStreamSize :=  ReadInteger;
    ReadStream(AMemStream, AStreamSize, false);
    ...
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to send multiple files at the same time over a single connection is to write the files in small chunks so you can intermix them - send chunk 1 of file A, then send chunk 1 of file B, then send chunk 2 of file A, and so on - where each chunk describes which file it belongs to.  Otherwise, you have to send each file on a separate connection.

Comment: Please help me with some sample coding, I don't know how to code using this technique. :(

Comment: Actually the files are quite small just about 3K each, how about put them into 1 single file stream, i meant, i don't know this is possible or not especially the possibility to get them out from the stream individually.

Comment: Putting all of the files into a single stream will not help you. You could just send each file one after the other instead, which would be much easier to code. Why do you want to send multiple files at the same time, instead of sending 1 file at a time? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just "thought" sending multiple files at once is giving better performance, was i wrong about that?

Comment: For sending a few small files, the processing overhead may not be worth the coding effort. But for sending many large files, it can provide some performance gains, but at the code of more complex coding. HTTP 2.0 and SPDY, for instance, offer multiplexing and pipelining semantics so multiple requests and multiple files can be in flight on a single connection at the same time.